# How to get own text from span not retrieving text of its children nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of dynamically formed HTML like this:

```
<span>
  10/10/2012
  <div class="calendar">
     lots of text elements here
  </div>
</span>
```

How to retrieve only `10/10/2012` text?

I tried `span.outerText`, but while it works in IE and Chrome, it doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: You shouldn't have a <div> inside a <span> in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

**With jQuery :**

```
var s = $('span').clone();
s.children().remove();
var text = s.text();
```

**Without jQuery :**

```
var text = '';
for (var i=0; i<spanElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
   var n =  spanElement.childNodes[i];
   if (n.nodeType==3) text += n.textContent;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/evowin/1/)

I suppose the code in your question was just a sample but just in case note that divs aren't allowed in spans (see [span permitted content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html)).

Comment: shouldn't he get the structure of his document right so he doesn't have to hack (and slay) the DOM tree apart like that?

Comment: @GungFoo Even with a valid HTML structure, the question keeps pertinent : you still have to find a way to get the first level text.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design problem. What's wrong with wrapping that first line in your `<span>` into another non-block element which you can easily select and manipulate?

like this:

```
<span>
  <span class="date">10/10/2012</span>
  <div class="calendar">
  ....
</span>
```

your text will then be:

```
$('.date').text();
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: yours should. mine is also an answer!

Comment: Selector should be $('.date')

Answer (score 0):

If you use *jQuery*:

```
var text = $("span").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Another way:

```
var text = $("span").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best of ways, but I'd probably use innerHTLM and then parse through the content..

```
var tmpText = span.innerHTML;
var text = tmpText.subString(0,tmpText.indexOf('<'));
```

Not beautiful, but it should do the trick. At least in this case.. if you've got more text nested with other child nodes you'd have to do a bit more parsing.

Comment: Note that it works only for the text before the first child. It doesn't really answer *"How to get own text from span not retrieving text of its chilren nodes?"*.